# Count the number of equal words in a txt file

Tags: c, file

I want to make a programm that counts the number of words that are equal from an already created file by me. I have doubts on how am I going to implement it. For now I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char word[100];
   FILE *file;
   file=fopen("hello.txt", "r");

   if(file == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   printf("Write a word.\n");
   fgets(word, 100, stdin);

   return 0;
}
```

With this code I am able to get the word the user wish but now I don't know what to do next in order to count the number of times that word appears on the file. Can someone help?

[EDIT]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char word[100],oriword[100], c;
   int cont=0, condition;
   FILE *file;
   file=fopen("hello.txt", "r");

   if(file == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   printf("Write a word.\n");
   fgets(word, 100, stdin);

  do
  {
    c=fscanf(file, "%s", oriword);
    condition=strcmp(word, oriword);
    printf("%d ", condition);
    if(condition==0)
        cont=cont+1;

  }while(c != EOF);

  printf("That word appears %d times\n", cont);

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

I am able to read each word now, thanks to you guys. I tried to count how many times the same word appears but with this code I made it's still not working. Seems like strcmp value never returns 0 (I've input a word that is inside the file). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a good start. Now you need to learn (1) how to read all words in a file, and (2) how to compare two words for equality. Help on both these topics is readily available on the net.

Comment: The (2) it's pretty easy for me, the problem is (1) since I am not that experienced on files

Comment: There's a lot to this and you need to start somewhere. First I suggest just being able to separate the words into some kind of struct to hold them.

Comment: What constitutes a word? For simplicity, lets say only alpha and numeric characters do, so space, hypen, etc. are word delimiters. When you encouter them, what you've read so far is a word. Store it somewhere and keep reading more data until you hit the next delimiter.

Comment: [Here](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/classes/C_Tutor/node126.html) is one way to do the (1).

Comment: @legends2k but it's the building block for what he wants to do. He can count the number of times a word occurs and store it's size in the struct simplifying the other logic he needs to do.

Comment: If you want to do O(string length) bulk string comparisons, you should use an alphabetical tree (a tree where there is a child for each letter, I'm not sure what that's called) or a hash table. This avoids the issue where if you have 50 keywords, you have to call strcmp 50 times for each word in the input. If speed's not a big factor, don't bother with this though.

Comment: @Dom Sure, but to read the word itself, the OP doens't need it. I thought first learning chomping words is a decent milestone before getting to counting.

Comment: Agreed, but the interesting question is how best for the OP to store the words so that each can be compared once the read is complete? Without complicating the code with dynamically allocating storage for each word, a viable option would seem to be an statically declared array of char [n][32] initialized to 0. (the longest word in the abridged dictionary being 28 chars). A reasonable guess at 'n' would have to be made so the array was sufficiently large to hold each word in the file. Then I guess nested loops comparing each string against the other in brute force manner would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, however there is one issue. The output of fgets is not what you think it is. Instead of trying to use fgets it makes much more sense to just use scanf like such:

```
scanf("%s", word);
```

I've also cleaned up the file a bit and created a sample hello.txt and you can see the results below.

hello.txt:

```
hello world hi world
```

wordcount.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[100],oriword[100];
    int count=0;
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("hello.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Write a word.\n");

    //fgets(word, 100, stdin);
    scanf("%s", word);

    printf("Got %s\n",word);


    while(fscanf(file, "%s", oriword) != EOF)
    {
        if(strcmp(word, oriword))
        {
            count=count+1;
            printf("Match of %s so far %d have been found\n",word, count);
        }
        printf("Found %s\n",oriword);

    }

    printf("That word appears %d times\n", count);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

results:

```
Write a word.
world
Got world
Found hello
Match of world so far 1 have been found
Found world
Found hi
Match of world so far 2 have been found
Found world
That word appears 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but the problem you are having is that you must compare each word as it is read, to all the words you have read from the file up to that point. In order to do that, you must keep track of all the *unique* words you have read, and only add words you have not seen before to your collection of words. If you have seen a word before, you only want to update the count of the number of times you have seen that word.

While you ideally will not know how many words a file could have, or how big the file could be, you would want some way to allocate memory to store the words as needed. However, for purposes of this example, we will just set a maximum number of words to handle to prevent the code required to allocate/manage memory from clouding the logic of how to save the words and count the number of times they are seen.

To do that we will just set the maximum words to handle by defining a word limit `MAXW` of `100`. We will do the same for the maximum characters in any one word `MAXC` of `32` (the longest word in the abridged dictionary is 28 characters so 32 will do.)

To store all the words we have read from the file we will create an array 'read' to represent the *unique* words we have read and declare it as:

```
char read[MAXW][MAXC] = {{ 0 }};
```

We will declare a temporary buffer called 'word' to hold the current word and declare it as:

```
char word[MAXC] = {0};
```

While `fgets` is normally the proper choice for reading lines from a file, this is one of those rare cases where `fscanf` can be used without having to torture a format specification to fit the data. A format string for `fscanf` that will work nicely is:

```
fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\n]%*c", word);
```

Which will read up to a maximum of `32` characters not including a *space comma period or newline* (`[^ ,.\n]`) and then read and discard the *space comma period or newline* (`%*c`).

We will keep track of the number of times we see each word with a `seen` array declared like this:

```
size_t seen[MAXW] = {0};
```

All that remains is the logic to add the *unique* words we read to the `read` array and update the number of times we have seen them in the `seen` array. Rather than boring you with each step, I have commented a short example that will help you work your way through the logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXW 100
#define MAXC 32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* initialize variables & open file or stdin for reading */
    char read[MAXW][MAXC] = {{ 0 }};
    char word[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t seen[MAXW] = {0};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read 1st word into 'read' array, update index 'idx' */
    if (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        strcpy (read[idx], word);
        seen[idx]++;
        idx++;
    }
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file read error.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each word in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %32[^ ,.\n]%*c", word) == 1) {
        /* check against all prior words */
        for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            /* if word already in 'read', update 'seen' count */
            if (strcmp (read[i], word) == 0) {
                seen[i]++;
                goto present;   /* skip adding word to 'read' */
            }
        } /* add unseen words to 'read', update 'idx' */
        strcpy (read[idx], word);
        seen[idx]++;
        idx++;

    present:

        if (idx == MAXW) { /* check 'idx' against MAXW */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words exceeded.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    printf ("\nthe occurrence of words are:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("  %-28s : %zu\n", read[i], seen[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I put together a short nonsensical test file that will not exceed our limits:

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/words.txt
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. the fox jumps over the dog to avoid the squirrel.
the squirrel was in the path of captain jack sparrow a pirate so brave on the seven seas.
```

Running the test file through the code will produce the unique list of words and a count of each time they were seen:

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/file_words_occur <dat/words.txt

the occurrence of words are:

  the                          : 8
  quick                        : 1
  brown                        : 1
  fox                          : 2
  jumps                        : 2
  over                         : 2
  lazy                         : 1
  dog                          : 2
  to                           : 1
  avoid                        : 1
  squirrel                     : 2
  was                          : 1
  in                           : 1
  path                         : 1
  of                           : 1
  captain                      : 1
  jack                         : 1
  sparrow                      : 1
  a                            : 1
  pirate                       : 1
  so                           : 1
  brave                        : 1
  on                           : 1
  seven                        : 1
  seas                         : 1
```

Let me know if you have any questions. The only thing that might cause you to scratch your head is the shorthand used to either open the file provided as the first argument to the program or read from `stdin`:

```
FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

It is just a ternary operator that says if you have an argument `argc > 1 ?` then use it for the filename `fopen (argv[1], "r")` if not `:` then read from `stdin`. It is just a convenient way to say about 5 lines of code otherwise.